# Problem with including an "image" in shell program

Tags: shell, unix

I'm writing a program where at some point in my loop I want to print to output whatever is stored in a separate file (an image). But if I code it like this:

```
for c in $LIST 
do
    clear
    ./image.0
done
```

And the "image.0" file contains only an image like this:

```
+----+
|    |
|
|
|
|
|
========
```

Then when I run my program I get this message:

```
./image.0: 1: +----+: not found
./image.0: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

Why?

================================

So "cat" works, the image appears in the output but it's shifted in a strange way.
Do you know why this would happen?

```
   +----+
        |    |
        |
        |
        |
        |
        |
        ========
```

Answer: I put printf "\n" that fixed the shifting image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `./image.0`, you tell the shell to *execute* the image. You want to output it, so use `cat image.0`

Comment: Do you know why would the image shift like that (description added above)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the command `cat` to output the content of the `image.0` file

```
cat ./image.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`./something` will take `something` as a program and execute it. That's not what you want : to display the contents of a file, you can use the `cat` command, like this :

```
for c in $LIST 
do
    clear
    cat image.0
done
```